# Regex javascript confusion from variable

Tags: javascript, regex, iteration, mapping

I am mapping through a list of words (with random characters too) and the regex doesn't seem to work and ends up throwing an error.
I basically have a const variable (called `content`)
I want to search to see if there are certain words in the `content` variable.

so I have

```
if (list.words.map(lword=> {
    const re = new RegExp("/" + lword+ "\\/g");
    if (re.test(content)) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

But that just fails out and doesn't catch anything. I get a `Nothing to repeat` error.
Specifically: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: //Lu(*\/g/: Nothing to repeat`

I'm not sure how to search through `content` to see if it contains `lword`.

Comment: Related: [Is there a regex escape function in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript)

Comment: The way you use RegExp is wrong https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Comment: @epascarello it's not totally wrong, but if you pass a value to create a Regexp you need to escape that value, in order to replace special characters.

Comment: @muecas The leading and trailing `/` should not be there, the flags should not be there.... And yes, it has escaping issues....

Comment: @epascarello thats the part of "not totally wrong"; he needs to fix that ans escape the passed value, to replace special characters.

Comment: Using `map` with `if` makes no sense. `map` will return an array, and arrays are always truthy. Did you mean `list.words.some(...)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `new RegExp()` you don't put the delimiters and modifiers in the string, just the expression. The modifiers go in an optional second argument.

```
const re = new RegExp(lword, "g");
```

If you want to treat `lword` as a literal string to search for, rather than a regular expression pattern, you shouldn't use `RegExp` in the first place. Just search for it with `indexOf()`:

```js
const list = {
  words: ["this", "some", "words"]
};

const content = "There are some word here";

if (list.words.some(lword => content.indexOf(lword) != -1)) {
  console.log("words were found");
}
```

Comment: @Barmar
I tried that right now and I guess it got me closer but i still got
```Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /*damn/: Nothing to repeat```

Comment: You need to escape the regex https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript

Comment: @devOpGuy Why are you using `RegExp` if you don't want to process it as a regular expression pattern?

Comment: @Barmar
I don't see another way I can get a string(i trim it and all) and see if a substring is contained within it.
for example if I had the string `Development` and my substring was `elo`, how would I be able to see if that is in there? so I have an array of substrings so I'm trying to figure out if they exist in the main string.
@muecas i'll take a look at that now!

Comment: @devOpGuy I've added that to the answer.

Comment: I have a check of 
'''      if (list.words.indexOf(context) >= 0) {
            return true;
        }'''
I can't find it. am i doing the search in reverse?

Comment: This stills not solve the `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: //Lu(*\/g/: Nothing to repeat` error.

Comment: @muecas That's because he has invalid regular expressions in his array.

Comment: The proper answer will be to escape the passed `lword` to replace regex special characters.

Comment: @muecas No, the proper solution is to not use `RegExp` if it's not a regular expression.

Comment: @devOpGuy That's not the correct place to use `indexOf`. See my snippet.

Comment: @Barmar That is the correct answer! I tried this but i didn't treat it as a map and i think i got the `indexOf` confused a bit! This totally works, thank you!